# Angular - Bearer token

Tags: angular

I have an issue with authentication. When I use POSTMAN and add authorization header with a Bearer token, then everything is fine. But when I try a request by Angular, then I get response `405 Method Not Allowed`. I am using Angular 5 and my code is very simple:

```
    import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    const my_token = 'xxx'
    @Injectable()
    export class RequestService {
      makeRequest() {
        return this.http.get(api.get, {headers: new HttpHeaders(
          {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${my_token}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          })});
        }
     }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post postman request  and angular request info ?

Comment: `'Bearer my_token'` literally ? Please post your real code so that we see the issue

Comment: Is the request via postman also a GET request?

Comment: I have edited my example. Value of "Authorization" is "Bearer" followed by my token. But it doesn't work.

Comment: not sure about POSTMAN but for sure you have to write **'Autorization': \`Bearer ${my_token}\`** use the backquote

Comment: Event if I have value of "Authorization" as a straight string it still doesn't work.

Comment: What is the content of "api.get" ?? is it pointing to a URL valid for a GET request ??

HTTP_405 means the url you contacted exists but it does not accept GET requests

Comment: I copy - paste url from POSTMAN that works.

Comment: Do you know about CORS? Web browser prevents Javascript code from making a request from the different origin. You should enable CORS in backend code to allow the requested origin. An example Backend code in Java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905898/how-to-enable-cors-on-server-side-code-in-java

Comment: @Khaled I see in Dev Tools console that `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response` so this could be it. But if I can get proper response doing request by POSTMAN - could it still be the issue with a server CORS?

Comment: Postman does not implement CORS, just browsers. You could have started by telling us about the warning....  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: @David `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://my_endpoint.dev/ with MIME type application/json` - so this would be a server issue?

Comment: Yes, you need to implement cors on your server

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its an old issue but posting my thought for future readers. Will try to keep it short.

**THEORY**

To me the issue looks to be related to `CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing)`. When `www.domain1.com` makes a call to `www.domain2.com`, it is considered unsafe and browser needs some special headers to process your request (read `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`). Even `www.domain:1000.com` and `www.domain:2000.com` are considered separate domains.

**Why POSTMAN works?**

POSTMAN (even Telerik Fiddler) is a tool and not browser. Hence they does not care about any headers in response and renders the response. That's why they works. But when you run it via Angular, the app opens in browser and hence you see the issue of CORS playing the spoilsport.

**SOLUTION**

In the end, its an issue from server side code and not client side. Your Angular code is fine, you need to do either of the following to fix it.

1. **Permanent**: Enable CORS in server side code. Read about it on internet more.
2. **Temporary**: Install Chrome Extension for CORS (many free available) and enable the status of the plugin. Your Angular app should start working just fine.

**Side Note**

Regarding your code to add new request headers, should not it be part of some HTTP Interceptor?

I understand that you just wanted to present the issue and it may not be your original code. But still wanted to point this out.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to concat **my_token** with **Bearer**

Here's an example

```
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable()
export class RequestService {
     makeRequest() {
        return this.http.get(api.get, {headers: new HttpHeaders(
        {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer' + my_token,
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              })});
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have been more precise in my example. My value of "Authorization is a straight string.

Answer (score -1):

First concat **my_token** with **Bearer** like follows: 
    my_token1 = `Bearer ${my_token}`   
(use *backticks*)

then use it like 
    'Authorization': `${my_token1}`,