# Running into CORS error using Angular 7 as frontend, Backend as Java

Tags: java, angular, cors, frontend, backend

I am running two applications on my local desktop.

One is built in java which serves as the API, the other one is built in Angular which is the front-end application.

I am trying to access the backend data from Angular and I am running into an error :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

```
 public getMethod(): Observable<Availability[]> {
    return this.http
    .get(API_URL)
      .map(response => {

      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

I am doing something like this in Angular to grab the data, and the error keeps coming up.

My question is, is this an angular error, or a Backend error(Java)?

Comment: what kind of framework are you using in your back-end?

Comment: 100% back end error. Either use a reverse proxy to host your API on the same domain, or disable CORS headers.

Answer (score 1):

That's a backend error. You have to allow cors at your java backend. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905898/how-to-enable-cors-on-server-side-code-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to make http request in local is install a cors extension in your browser

As example, if you use Google Chrome install it:

[Allow-Control-Allow-Origin Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)

So, enable the cors clicking in the button and make a request :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `proxy.conf.json` in the root of your project next to `package.json`.

Here's an example.

```
{
    "/service/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

Add your `proxy.conf.json` to `serve` `options` in `angular.json`. As in:

```
 "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            }
          }
        }
```

That's it. Just `ng serve` as you usually do and you can start proxying to your server. Make sure you don't manually offer `host url` in your `http` calls. Just request from `/service`.